# How do you detect a certain block placed in area and the placing player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to be able to detect if someone placed a certain block near my server's spawn point and remove the block while warning them to not do it again.

Comment: Why not just use spawn protection, which does this by default?

Answer (score -3):

You can use the commands

> BlockPlaceEvent true
> fill XYZ 0 "the square area you want to remove blocks"

and
for deleting and alerts.

> tell @p "do not touch my spawn"

use this one for the message
for more commands click here ->
[Minecraft commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Your commands seems misleading or rather incomplete. Please, improve your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).